# useEffect not called if invoke setState(Obj) based on an Object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

What I need is :
1 after the first time component mounted, I gave it a state with an Object

```
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(option);
```

and that option is imported from another file:

```
export const option = {prop1:"prop1"}
```

and then, in the useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    option = {
      prop1:"prop1"
    };

  setOption(option);

  });
```

so the effect will not called because the option object have the same Memory address . and I tried this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    let newOption = Object.assign({},option);

    newOption.prop1 = "newProp";

    setOption(newOption);

  },[newOption]);
```

I also add a condition to avoid an infinite loop. but since the newOption is created every time , it still Led to an infinite loop.

so one solution is to change the condition to `JSON.stringify(option)`, but it's there a better way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your expected result? Are you just trying to save a prop value to state and update state whenever the prop value changes?

Comment: yes, I need to initialize my component with a default option(object), and I will change the option later. but only change the object's property. so it will not rerender component.

Comment: When do you want to make this change? Is it just once when the component is mounted?

Comment: Ok, initializing state with *some object*, is clear. What isn't clear is the effect part, later. Updating state in React involves pure functions that return new state (objects). What is your use case for trying to circumvent how react works?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, Try this:

```js
// Your imported option
const option = { prop1: "prop1" }

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      ...option, // copying your imported option into state
      prop2: "prop2" // setting a new state
    })
    console.log("useEffect render")
  }, [/* no dependencies run only once */])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{state.prop1}</h2>
      <h2>{state.prop2}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```